# Calculate Average values from file

Tags: java, file-io, average

I have a text file with 5 columns, 9 ints in each of the of columns.
Looks like this: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
I import the textile into my java program using File

```
fileName = new File("Example1.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
```

I want to calculate the average of each of the columns, how would I do that? I am thinking

```
    int index;
            index = 0;
        if (inFile.hasNext()) {
                    do {
                        Example[index] = inFile.nextInt();
                        index++;

                    } while (inFile.hasNext());
                }
inFile.close();
```

How would I find the average?

Comment: ...find the he average of what?

Comment: @Matthias Of each of the columns.  He states it quite clearly

Comment: Have an array to store the sum of the elements in every column. Then divide each element of the array by the number of elements in every column. Every element of the resulting array is the average of the corresponding column.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Oh, I missed that sentence.

Comment: @lodo has a good plan.  You'l need to reset your index into the array every time you get a newline.  You'll want to keep a count of lines.

Answer (score 0):

The average of a series of numbers is their sum divided by the number of numbers.

It should be a simple modification to go from looping through and storing numbers in an array, to looping through each set of 5x9 numbers and calculating a total for each column, then dividing at the end by (9 * numLines).

```
int index = 0;
int numRows = 0;
int columnTotals[5];
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            columnTotals[col] += inFile.nextInt();
        }
    }
    numRows++;
}
inFile.close();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(columnTotals[col]/(9*numRows));
}
```

Comment: The OP asks for column averages, not line averages.

Comment: A real solution would involve two loops.  One for each line and one for each column in a line.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I changed it to exactly that after lodo's comment.

Comment: I think you have the loops out of order.  You'll get a row then, another row.  Your code expects a column, then another column.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got time to check this so something is probably wrong.  Test this before you trust it.

Anyway, think about using mod `%` to help simplify this problem.  I'm mostly reusing Beth's code.

```
int index = 0;
int numRows = 0;
int columnTotals[5];
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    columnTotals[index%5] += inFile.nextInt();
    index++;
}
inFile.close();
numRows = index / 5

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(columnTotals[i]/(numRows));
}
```

Be aware that this last line is performing integer division.  You might want to cast to a double to get more detailed averages.

Answer (score -1):

aver[x] = Example[x].sum() / Example[x].count()